# Strategy to designing grammar for a LR(1) parser

Tags: parsers

Is it better to think about tokens from right to left and perform right factoring on grammar for an LR(1) parser? As apposed to thinking about tokens left to right and doing left factoring on grammar for an LL(1) parser.

Example java import statement.

```
S1 -> S2 ;
S2 -> S5
S2 -> S3 id
S2 -> S4 *
S3 -> S5 as
S4 -> S5 .
S5 -> S4 id
S5 -> import id
```

Where `S1` is the starting rule.

Am I correct in thinking LR(1) grammar is no more difficult than LL(1) grammar, but you just need to think about tokens in reverse order. Kinda like LR(1) is the dual of LL(1)?

It also seems like you can simply reverse the order of the rules and construct a sort-of continuous passing style in the grammar in order to convert LR(1) grammar into LL(1) grammar like so:

```
S5 -> import id C1
C1 -> S2
C1 -> as S3
C1 -> . S4
S2 -> ; S1
S1 ->
S3 -> id S2
S4 -> * S2
S4 -> id C1
```

Further more. If you imagine Java is backwards token-wise and an import statement is written like `;s as swing.javax import` for example. Then you create an LL(1) grammar for that. And with your LL(1) grammar, you reverse the parts of each rule. Then you end up with the original LR(1) grammar at the top of this post. This leads me to believe LR(1) is the dual of LL(1).

A language running backwards should be just as expressive as a language running forwards token-wise, as all the information of the sentence is still there. Maybe LL(1) and LR(1) are in fact equal in expressive power as each other.

Comment: Do you understand why $LL(1)$ doesn't support left factoring and left recursive? And why left factoring and left recursive and right recursive doesn't create any problem in bottom up parser like $LR(1)?$

Comment: LL(1) can take the wrong direction within a choice operator if left factoring is not performed. And most (but not all) implementations of LL(1) hit an infinite loop or stack overflow when their is left recursion, because it is top down. The exception is ANTLR, it is LL, but uses an oracle to perform direct left recursion. LR(1) does not have those problems because it is working from bottom up in shift reduce style. Guess that means they are not duels of each other.

Comment: By "difficulty". I mean the difficultly to write the grammar for a given language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not difficult to write grammars, and particularly not LR(k) grammars (despite all the claims to the contrary you'll find floating around). You should start by trying to write down a simple description of the language which reflects the actual structure of the language. In many cases, that's easier to do if you allow yourself to use repetition ("list of"), alternation, and optionality, as you might do in English.

(I've tried to address some of your specific questions after the rather long example.)

For example, some hypothetical language might be a *program*, consisting of a *list of declarations*, with a *declaration* being a *variable declaration* or a *function declaration*.

A *variable declaration* is a *type* followed by a *comma-separated list of variables with optional initializer* followed by a `;`. A *variable with optional initializer* is a *name*, optionally followed by an `=` and an `expression`.

Since this is just an example, I'll stop there and write it out, using a formalism which includes the above-mentioned operators; this is usually called an "extended" BNF (EBNF), which is more of a concept than a standard. (That is, there are a lot of different extensions, all more or less functionally equivalent, but with different textual manifestations). So here's my personal non-standard EBNF:

#### Fonts:

- $\it{<italics>}$ are non-terminals (surrounded by angle brackets because I can't figure out how to make a good-looking hyphen in MathJax).
- $\it{CAPS}$ are terminals defined by a lexical grammar. (eg. $\it{IDENTIFIER})$
- $\tt{typewriter}$ are literal tokens. (eg. $\tt{begin}$ or $\tt{\{}$)

#### Operators (coloured red to distinguish them from literals):

- $\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\mid}}}$: separates alternatives.
- $\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{[}}}...\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{]}}}$: indicates that $...$ is optional.
- $\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}...\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}$: indicates that $...$ can be repeated (at least once).
- $\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}...\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{/}}}\;\tt{,}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}$: indicates that $...$ can be repeated, separated with $\tt{,}$ (or some other punctuation token)

(That last one -- the interleave operator -- is particularly divergent; it is not even present in many EBNF variants, although it's incredibly useful. This particular version is mine and mine alone, so don't expect it to work in an EBNF tool.)

With that, the start of the grammar:
$$\begin{align}\it{<program>}&\to\it\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}\it{<declaration>}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}\\
\it{<declaration>}&\to\it{<function\;declaration>}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\mid}}}\;\it{<variable\;declaration>}\\
\it{<variable\;declaration>}&\to\it{TYPE}\enspace\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}\it{<initialiser>}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{/}}}\;\tt{,}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}\enspace\tt{;}\\
\it{<initialiser>}&\to\it{IDENT}\enspace\color{red}{\large{\tt{[}}}\tt{=}\enspace\it{<expression>}\color{red}{\large{\tt{]}}}\\
\end{align}$$
Now, we can mechanically turn that into an LR(1) grammar, say for the popular Bison parser generator, using macro transformations for the EBNF operators:

| EBNF | Bison |
| --- | --- |
| $A\to\alpha\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{|}}}\enspace\beta$ | `A: α | β` |
| $A\to\;\alpha\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{[}}}\;\beta\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{]}}}$ | `A: α | α β` |
| $A\to\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}\;\alpha\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}$ | `A: α | A α` |
| $A\to\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}\;\alpha\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{/}}}\;\tt{,}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}$ | `A: α | A ',' α` |

(Some of the above require the introduction of intermediate non-terminals, if they are used other than at the top-level of a production.)

That produces the following Bison grammar snippet:

```
program
    : declaration
    | program declaration
declaration
    : variable-declaration
    | function-declaration
variable-declaration
    : TYPE initialiser-list ';'
initialiser-list
    : initialiser
    | initialiser-list ',' initialiser
initialiser
    : IDENT
    | IDENT '=' expression
```

OK, let's do your `import` statement, which I think is in some ways as fictional as my language above. Just a couple of notes first:

- I'm not really a Java programmer, but I don't see any reference to the `import type as alias` syntax in the JLS (version 18). Still, it's reasonable to build a grammar which includes it, so we'll do that.
- Your grammar seems to be for a sequence of `import` statements, rather than for a single `import` statement. That seems unrealistic; it's just one of many possible declarations, and it should fit into a syntax like the one above, for example by modifying *declaration* to be $$\it{<declaration>}\to\;\it{<variable\;declaration>}\;\mid\;\it{<function\;declaration>}\;\mid\;\it{<import\;declaration>}$$ and then making $\it{<import\;declaration>}$ produce a single declaration. That's also a better match for the semantics (in which there's no category for a sequence of declarations of the same kind). So that's what we'll do.

That said, the JLS defines four types of `import` declarations, which is basically a product of two binary choices: *type* or *static*, and *single* or *on-demand*. Ignoring the minor detail about which of the identifiers is allowed to be one of the semi-reserved words (`permits`, `record`, `sealed`, `var`, and `yield`), these can all be summarised by one simple EBNF syntax:

$$\begin{align}\it{import\;declaration}&\to\tt{import}\enspace\color{red}{\large{\tt{[}}}\;\tt{static}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{]}}}\enspace\color{red}{\large{\tt{\{}}}\it{IDENT}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{/}}}\tt{.}\color{red}{\large{\tt{\}}}}\enspace\color{red}{\large{\tt{[}}}\;\tt{.}\enspace\tt{*}\enspace\color{red}{\large{\tt{|}}}\enspace\tt{as}\enspace\it{IDENT}\;\color{red}{\large{\tt{]}}}\enspace\tt{;}\\
\end{align}$$
corresponding to the Bison grammar, where list needs its own non-terminal and the alternatives and optionalities translate into six productions:

```
import
    : "import" dotted-name ';'
    | "import" dotted-name '.' '*' ';'
    | "import" dotted-name '.' "as" IDENT ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name '.' '*' ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name '.' "as" IDENT ';'
dotted-name
    : IDENT
    | dotted-name '.' IDENT
```

Even though that's a lot longer than the EBNF, I believe it's not that hard to follow (nor to write), unlike the LL version in your question.

For the cherry, I'll add (a very cut-down) *function declaration*, and change `TYPE` to a dot-separated list of identifiers, closer to the Java grammar. Then we can verify that it's an LALR(1) grammar by passing it through bison. Here's the full grammar (although for testing purposes, I'm treating `expression` and `statement` as terminals):

```
%token IDENT statement expression
%%
program
    : declaration
    | program declaration
declaration
    : variable-declaration
    | function-declaration
    | import-declaration

variable-declaration
    : type initialiser-list ';'
initialiser-list
    : initialiser
    | initialiser-list ',' initialiser
initialiser
    : IDENT
    | IDENT '=' expression

function-declaration
    : type IDENT parameter-list block
parameter-list
    : '(' ')'
    | typed-name-list
typed-name-list
    : type IDENT
    | typed-name-list ',' type IDENT
block
    : '{' statement-list '}'
statement-list
    : %empty
    | statement-list statement
    | statement-list declaration

import-declaration
    : "import" dotted-name ';'
    | "import" dotted-name '.' '*' ';'
    | "import" dotted-name '.' "as" IDENT ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name '.' '*' ';'
    | "import" "static" dotted-name '.' "as" IDENT ';'
dotted-name
    : IDENT
    | dotted-name '.' IDENT

type: dotted-name
```

And that works, first time. No errors, no warnings, and no conflicts:

```
$ bison -Wall -v -o minijava.c minijava.y
$
```

(See note 1).

Now, that grammar is definitely not LL. There are various non-terminals which start with the same terminal, and there's lots of left recursion. LR doesn't care about any of that. (And it doesn't care about right recursion, either; I just avoid it because it uses more parser stack.) In this case, I could make it LL by left-factoring and eliminating left recursion, but:

- that's a lot of work;
- the result, like the example you provide, is very hard to read and therefore does not serve to document the syntax of the grammar;
- and it might not have worked, because LR is simply a more powerful parsing algorithm.

In short, it's not necessary to try to force a grammar to follow a particular model of how a parser might function. You can --and, in my opinion, should-- aim for grammars which capture the essence of the syntax in a natural and easily understood way (easily understood by programmers not well-versed in parsing theory, that is), and that's often easier to do if you don't have to apply the grammatical transformations necessary to make linear-time top-down parsing possible.

It's true that LR parsing can be considered a dual of LL, in a certain sense. But it's not that LR is LL applied to the reverse of the input, nor is it the case that some simple grammar transformation (like reversing the grammar) will turn a language into an LL grammar. LR parsing is strictly more powerful than LL parsing; proofs and examples can be found in any textbook on formal language theory. The duality shows up in a comparison of certain algorithms, in particular the algorithms for determining whether a given CFG is LL(k)/LR(k). These algorithms are not the same --they don't have the same asymptotic complexity, for example-- but there are aspects which show the parallels. These are explored in [*Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen, On LL(k) Parsing* (1988)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(82)91016-6), which is definitely worth reading if you're interested in the theory. (It won't help you write better grammars, though :-) ).

The dualism is also noted in the comparison between GLL and GLR parsing in various papers by [Elizabeth Scott and Adrian Johnstone](https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/research/languages/csle/GLLparsers.html). Again, these are different algorithms; both can parse any context-free language in polynomial time (but not always linear time), but particular languages can have different asymptotic performance with the two frameworks. Scott & Johnstone argue that the GLL framework produces a simpler algorithm. The value of both GLR and GLL parsing is that it does not require any grammar transformation to make a grammar parsable. It might still require some work to make the language unambiguous, which is useful for practical formal processing. But even that is not a requirement. For example, C++ has a number of ambiguities which can only be resolved by implementing criteria described in the text of the C++ standard, some of which have no context-free description. Even so, it's demonstrably practical, although not necessarily parsable in linear time.

As a final note, I recognise that it is not always as easy to write grammars as my above example seems to indicate. Many languages occasionally require more than one token of lookahead; while it is true that you can always transform an LR(k) grammar into an LR(1) grammar from which the same parse tree can be extracted, that transformation is not of much practical assistance, since the resulting grammars are enormous. If you have a language whose "natural" grammar is LR(2) (or worse), you're generally better off using some lexical or semantic hack or switching to GLL/GLR parsing, rather than transforming the grammar into something parsable with an LR(1) parser. A similar comment applies to certain parsing ambiguities easily resolved with operator-precedence techniques but tedious to resolve using a context-free grammar, which is why most parser generators provide precedence relationships as a disambiguation technique. (One example of such an ambiguity is the infamous "dangling-else"; an LALR(1) grammar exists, but it's easy to get wrong and it is certainly not self-documenting, while the precedence comparison is almost trivial.)

#### Notes

1. Because that grammar does not include statements or expressions, it's actually hiding one pain point which may show up in a grammar for the full language, related to the difficulty in deciding whether a given `IDENT` will turn out to be the name of a type or the name of a variable or function. This is particular painful in C, where it cannot be solved without context-sensitivity (that is, letting the lexer look the name up in a symbol table to decide whether it has previously been declared as a type). Extra-grammatical semantic checks like that can be easier in an LL grammar because there's no need to worry about the semantic action being executed speculatively for a production which later turns out to be inapplicable. Most LR parser generators don't allow semantic checks; ANTLR, on the other hand, uses them as a standard practice.
2. The two-volume textbook by the same authors on Parsing Theory ([Volume 1](https://www.springer.com/book/9783540137207) and [Volume 2](https://www.springer.com/book/9783540517320)) is also a treasure. Sadly, unlike the above-mentioned article, you probably will only find a freely readable version in an academic library, and the outrageous costs of academic texts makes purchase only practical for the highly-motivated or independently-wealthy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your long answer. It was more of a Kotlin import statement, than Java. For some reason I thought they had the same grammar. There is still something troubling me, which I can post as a separate question. The grammar for type in Kotlin. I have no idea how to eliminate the shift-reduce error for a LR(1) for it. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#type . The problem occurs through the function type having a reciever type (ignoing modifiers / annotations). Maybe you can shed some light on it. If not, I can make a new question.

Comment: T -> a,
T -> F,
F -> T,
F -> T T.
Thats a summary of what still bothers me. I'll make it a new question.

Comment: @clinux: Did you figure out the issue with receiver type? Or did you decide it wasn't a good match for this site? I was about to answer your question, but it vanished.

Comment: I found a solution on my own. Thank you! Sorry for making it disappear as you were going to answer it.

Comment: I was basically able to repeat grammar rules in a few places to avoid the shift-reduce conflict. I'm using lalrpop for rust as my parser generator.

Comment: Its funny though, I do believe it is possible to algorithmically transform LR(1) grammar into LL(1) grammar. There seems to be a common pattern. S1 -> S2 ; becomes S2 -> ; S1 and S2 -> S3 id becomes S3 -> id S2. Its like a very simple rule transformation, provided that the LR(1) rules always start with a non-terminal and finish with a terminal. C1 only appears because I broke that pattern of non-terminal followed by terminal.

Comment: The action code attached to those rules would get broken from the transformations though. Its really just getting the grammar to accept the same language.

Comment: Since the proof that LR is more powerful than LL exists for decades and can be found in elementary textbooks,  I'm afraid your belief falls into the same category as, say, perpetual motion machines. Of course, there is a subset of LR languages which are also LL languages, so if you never try a language outside of the subset you will always succeed. Try parsing the dangling-else with an LL grammar. (The LR solution is in the Dragon Book, Wikipedia, and many other places).

Comment: Very true! LR(1) grammars with right recursion can not follow that automatic transformation.  Automatic transformation can lower the rules to two symbols each on the right hand side, and new rules can be added to insure the first part on the right hand side of the rule is non-terminal. But no automatic transformation can handle that right recursion that I know of.

Comment: By the way, if all your rules consist of a terminal followed by a non-terminal, then your language is regular (i.e recognisable by a DFA). Such languages are LL. But most useful languages cannot be written in that form (anything using parentheses for nesting, for example).

Comment: Same if they all consist of a non-terminal followed by a terminal  (Left linear and right linear forms of a regular grammar.)

Comment: I would really like to see an example of an LR(1) grammar that can not be written as a LL(1) grammar. That would be very enlightening.

Comment: I gave you one already. *Try parsing the dangling-else with an LL grammar. (The LR solution is in the Dragon Book, Wikipedia, and many other places)*